# ¿Cómo puedo verificar si "nick" o "email" existen en la base de datos? (validación app android)

Tags: android, android-studio, webservice

Quiero hacer una validación en la cual se permita un registro siempre y cuando no existan ni el email ni el nick en la base de datos. Para ello, uso web service. El archivo php es este:

```
<?php

include "connection.php";

$nick = $_POST["newNick"];
$email = $_POST["newEmail"];
$password = $_POST["newPassword"];

$query = "INSERT INTO `user` (`nick`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('".$nick."', '".$email."', '".$password."')";

mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

y el método para la inserción y validación es este:

```
private void serviceExecution (String URL, final String nick, final String email, final String password){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            //Si el registro es correcto, se ejecuta este método.
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                if (response.isEmpty()){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario registrado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El usuario, el email o la contraseña existe en la base de datos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            //Si hay algún problema, se ejecuta este método.
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){

            //Se recogen los datos.
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("newNick", nick);
                params.put("newEmail", email);
                params.put("newPassword", password);

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

}
```

La cuestión es que, al poner un nick idéntico a otro que tenga en la tabla, sí dice el error, pero al poner un email ya existente o password ya existente SÍ hace el registro.

Dicho sea de paso, me gustaría que SOLAMENTE se comprobara el nick y el email, pero no consigo hacer esto.

Espero que me echéis una mano. Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes definir que esos campos serán únicos, para eso se necesita el uso de la constraint `UNIQUE`

Ej.:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios
(
id_usuario int PRIMARY KEY,
nick char(50) NOT NULL,
email char(50) NOT NULL,
password char(50),
UNIQUE (email,nick )
)
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Y por casualidad hay alguna forma de saber si lo que está mal es el email o el nick? (para informar al usuario)

Comment: En ese caso deberías poner como `UNIQUE` a cada campo y luego caputurar el error e informarlo https://manuales.guebs.com/mysql-5.0/error-handling.html . Soy nuevo aquí y entiendo que eso ya sería otra pregunta. Me alegro haber sido de ayuda :). Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Eres un genio. Grande!